# Convert time/tick in Python MIDI MIDO read/save file

Tags: midi, mido

The following program uses MIDO to read 'g1.mid' then save it to 'g1_new.mid'. My question is that: in reading the file, 'msg.time' is a float value, but in saving the file, 'time in Message' is an integer in tick. How do we convert 'msg.time' to 'tick in message' in this case?

```
from mido import MidiFile 
from mido import Message, MidiTrack

mid = MidiFile()
track = MidiTrack()
mid.tracks.append(track)

for msg in MidiFile('g1.mid'):
    if (not msg.is_meta):
        if (msg.type == 'note_on'):
            # how to convert msg.time to tick to fill in '?'
            track.append(Message('note_on', note=msg.note, velocity=msg.velocity, time=?))
        elif (msg.type == 'note_off'):
            # how to convert msg.time to tick to fill in '?'
            track.append(Message('note_off', note=msg.note, velocity=msg.velocity, time=?))
        elif (msg.type == 'program_change'):
            track.append(Message('program_change', program=msg.program, channel=msg.channel))

mid.save('g1_new.mid')
```

Note: This piece of code is in a project about music generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over the `MidiFile` object itself, the time stamps are explicitly converted:

```py
class MidiFile(object):
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        ...
        tempo = DEFAULT_TEMPO
        for msg in merge_tracks(self.tracks):
            # Convert message time from absolute time
            # in ticks to relative time in seconds.
            if msg.time > 0:
                delta = tick2second(msg.time, self.ticks_per_beat, tempo)
            else:
                delta = 0

            yield msg.copy(time=delta)

            if msg.type == 'set_tempo':
                tempo = msg.tempo
```

So just iterate over `mid.tracks` (or over the merged tracks) directly.

Comment: Dear CL: The program can get ticks in "for msg in merge_tracks(mid.tracks)." Thanks for your comment.